# How can I change the selected option of a select box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title says, how can I change the selected option of a select box using jQuery?

I have something like this:

```
<select id="v_lenguaje" name="lenguaje">
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
<option value="Italian">Italian</option>
<option value="French">French</option>
<option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

By default it shows 'English', and what i want is after an ajax call the selected option change. I tried many codes but it doesn't worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var your_value='French';
$('#v_lenguaje').val(your_value);
```

Comment: well thanks, that simple code worked well. I've been trying some longer ones and got aground there

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#v_lenguaje').val('Italian');
```

just use like above, giving the option value

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XYwDt/)**